# Why parseInt(['1', '2', '3']) return 1?

Tags: javascript

```
parseInt([1,2,3])
1
parseInt([[1,2,3]])
1
parseInt([[['101',2,3]]], 2)
5
```

tested with Chrome12, Firefox3.6, IE6, IE8.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to pass it arrays, according to the mozilla docs, the first parameter is supposed to be a string, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt...

Comment: Why parseInt an array?!?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because, `[1,2,3].toString()` will return `1,2,3`, hence why you get a `1` on the first two lines. `parseInt()` will stop looking for a numeric value after it hits a `NaN`, which in this case is the comma `,`. That's where it stops parsing and returns whatever number it has found so far.

Answer (score 5):

`parseInt` will take the first thing it can reasonably get in amongst your mess of arrays - in this case, that's `'101'`.

And then,

```
>>> parseInt(101, 2)
5
```

Because 101<sub>2</sub> = 5<sub>10</sub>

Comment: As mentioned by others, an important aspect of this is the way that `parseInt(object)` casts to string. This is important in that that's how it gets the `101` to work with. But I *think* that what @clyfish was puzzling about was the radix and binary parsing.

Answer (score 4):

That is because `parseInt` expects a string as a first parameter, and if it is not given that, it converts it to string

`parseInt([1,2,3])` is equivalent to `parseInt([1,2,3].toString())`, which is `parseInt("1,2,3")`

Similarly for other cases

Answer (score 0):

It takes the first value in the array and then use the radix value to convert the value into `int`.

`parseInt([50,2,3])`
Will return you `50`

```
parseInt([[['101',2,3]]], 2)
```

Return 5 because the first element `101` base `2` is int `5 base 10`.